# R script or batch file to automatically install latest software build

Tags: r, batch-file, installation, automation

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically install software updates. There are regularly new software builds that are created in a known directory and have their own folders. In either R or a batch file that I can execute in an R script, I'd like to write a script that will check to see if any new builds have been created within the past 24 hours. I was wondering if there was a way to use the "Date modified" column in windows explorer to make that check. So if today is 06/27/2016, the script would look for any folders that have a "Date modified" after "Current Date" - 24 hours. Then it would navigate to that folder and execute the executable file and auto-install.

Is this even feasible?

**EDIT**: r2evans provided a very thorough answer to most of my question but I wanted to make an update to show how far this brings me.

This is the way I've implemented his answer.

```
path <- "//Path/to/Folders/"
df <- file.info(list.files(path, full.names = TRUE))

df <- rownames(df)[ df$mtime > Sys.time() - 60*60*24 ]
```

This would work perfectly if I had a single directory of files I was looking for. However, I need this analyzes a series of subdirectories that have the executable (`.msi`) files in them. So when I print df after it has been modified to look for what has changed in the last 24 hours, it only gives me the name of a folder.

```
//Path/to/Folders/FolderName
```

I was thinking about using `Shell` instead of `system2` to execute the file. I execute several batch files in my full script using Shell like this: `shell(paste(shQuote("\\\\SERVER\\d$SERVER\\Path\\to\\the\\folder\\file.bat")), "cmd")`

I tried implementing that like this: `shell(paste(shQuote("\\\\SERVER\\d$SERVER\\Path\\to\\the\\folder\\dffolderName\\*")), "cmd")` but this gave this error:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The network name cannot be found.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'cmd /c "\\SERVER\d$\SERVER\Path\to\dffolderName\*"' had status 1 
2: In shell(paste(shQuote("\\\\SERVER\\d$SERVER\\Path\\to\\the\\folder\\dffolderName\\*")),  :
  '"\\SERVER\d$\SERVER\Path\to\dffolderName\*"' execution failed with error code 1
```

Additionally, importantly, how would I add in the `df` variable to `Shell` so that path becomes variable?

**EDIT 2**: Here's a working example of my shell cmd line.

I created a test batch file to execute. This batch file should do all the relevant things that are being done in the R script (i.e. pulling variables in and running from a remote server).

```
@ECHO off

set var1=%1
set var2=%2

ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
ECHO This batch file is working

pause
```

Then try this R script:

```
var1 <- 1
var2 <- 2

shell(paste(shQuote("\\\\SERVER\\d$\\SERVER\\Path\\To\\the\\File\\TestBat.bat"), var1, var2), "cmd")
```

Comment: I love R so don't get me wrong... but why do you want to use R for this task?

Comment: I don't have to. But I'm running a script to collect and analyze data for this software using R so it makes it more convenient. Ultimately, I want to add this script to the task scheduler and just sit back and let it do its thing.

Comment: @Dason That's why I also said I wouldn't mind using a batch file because I could just execute that inside the R script.

Comment: Are you more concerned with dealing with folder of folders (`list.files(..., recursive=TRUE)`, or with the explicit use of `shell` on a windows machine? Can you show a working example of your command that is run on the command line vice from `shell`?

Comment: When you demonstrate trying `cmd /c "\\..."`, is that your plan for running an app that is newer? Does that work as is on the (non-R) command line? As for using `df`, you can use `paste` or `sprintf` to create the command string, then pass that to `shell`.

Comment: @r2evans I created an edit that has a working example.

Comment: I got it to work with `shell(shQuote(paste("//SERVER/path/to/testbat.bat", var1, var2), "cmd"), "cmd")`, though windows needed me to already be authenticated to the server (otherwise it would give the error). If you open that network path in (say) windows explorer first, getting all the auth correct, does the line in R still give you an error?

Comment: @r2evans Running it gives me this: `CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'//msabuild/FinalBuilds/JMPT/paste' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'cmd /c "//msabuild/FinalBuilds/JMPT/paste(df)/*"' had status 1 
2: In shell(shQuote(paste("//msabuild/FinalBuilds/JMPT/paste(df)/*")),  :
  '"//msabuild/FinalBuilds/JMPT/paste(df)/*"' execution failed with error code 1`

Comment: @r2evans It might be worth adding that I implemented a paste in the line so that it would use the value of `df`.

`shell(shQuote(paste("//SERVER/Path/To/paste(df)/*")), "cmd")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115869/discussion-between-r2evans-and-david).

Comment: Have you had any luck, @David?

Comment: I actually had to abandon this endeavor to work on something else that was given priority. I think I may have figured out my problem. I think going the route of  `paste0` instead of `paste`

Answer (score 1):

You can find which files within a directory have been updated recently with something like this:

```
path <- "path/to/files/"
df <- file.info(list.files(path, full.names = TRUE))
```

`df` is just a data.frame with some basic fields on the files. For a particular path on my machine (with docker stuff for confluent-platform):

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  7 variables:
#  $ size : num  0 1434 0 0 0
#  $ isdir: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#  $ mode :Class 'octmode'  int [1:5] 511 438 511 511 511
#  $ mtime: POSIXct, format: "2016-06-15 08:01:41" "2016-06-27 10:07:12" ...
#  $ ctime: POSIXct, format: "2016-06-15 08:00:22" "2016-06-15 08:49:39" ...
#  $ atime: POSIXct, format: "2016-06-15 08:01:41" "2016-06-27 09:15:55" ...
#  $ exe  : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...
```

The file names themselves are the row names, so you can either access them directly with:

```
rownames(df)
# [1] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/confluent-3.0.0"    
# [2] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/docker-kafka-notes" 
# [3] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0"
# [4] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/tmp"                
# [5] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/zookeeper-3.4.8"
```

From here, it's simple enough to filter on the `mtime` (modification time):

```
rownames(df)[ df$mtime > Sys.time() - 60*60*24 ]
# [1] "C:\\Users\\r2/Projects/kafka/docker-kafka-notes"
```

(I have only modified that one file in the last day.)

If your next step (actually updating the application) is good with a full path, then all is good. If not and you need to remove the leading stuff, there are two easy methods for doing that:

1. Change into the directory first with `setwd("/path/to/dir")` and then `df <- file.info(list.files())`; or
2. Run `basename(...)` on the returned (filtered) file names, returning the filename without its leading path.

I prefer the latter (not wanting to rely on or change the current working directory), but that's just personal preference.

Now actually effecting the update is a different issue. If you're simply going to "run the updated application", then I recommend looking into [`?system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html).

Comment: This is a very thorough answer thank you. However, there are a few things I'm still curious about. I'm going to make an edit to address it so I can show code better.

Comment: the Edit is up. took longer than I thought or I would have waited to comment until I had made it.